# Sails js - ordering form list

Tags: sails.js

How would one create a "list" on an order form page that items could be added to when they are added to an order.

Example: I have a dropdown box with a list of items I pick an item and add it to an order form when I just have to set the qty after it is added.

Comment: SO is unfortunately not a codewriting service.  If you can provide code of what you've attempted, we can help you with problems in that.

Comment: Please add code to represent the current state of your attempt at this problem, or show us the code you do have and what you're trying to figure out.

Comment: Sorry I was not asking for code was more asking if the method sounded correct or if it was going about it wrong. Sorry new to sails and still getting familiar with it.